# Hide template button based on user- odoo 10

Tags: xml, odoo-10

I need to hide the 'new message' button which include the top of the mail message history.It can be only visible for the managers.I tried it in several ways. But its not working.
Here is my code

```
    <templates>
        <t t-name="mail.Chatter">
            <div class="o_chatter">
                <div class="o_chatter_topbar">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary o_chatter_button_new_message" title="Send a message" groups="toweriq_pm.group_manager">
                        New message
                    </button>
                    <button t-if="widget.options.display_log_button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link o_chatter_button_log_note" title="Log a note. Followers will not be notified.">
                        Log an internal note
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </t>
    </templates>
```

can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

I just restrict by overriding JS method. First I create a field in my custom module to check whether the logged in user is a manager or user for my custom module.
This is my python code for that

```py
class my_tasks(models.Model):
_inherit ='project.task'
identify_manager   = fields.Boolean(compute='check_user')

@api.model
def check_user(self):
    data = {}
    # search current user id
    user_id = self.env['res.users'].search([('id', '=', self.env.user.id)])
    # search the module category which called as My module
    user_my_category_id = self.env['ir.module.category'].search([('name', '=', 'My Module')])
    # search the manager id which belongs to my module category
    user_new_id = self.env['res.groups'].search(
        [('category_id', '=', user_my_category_id.id), ('name', '=', "Manager")]).id

    # search using count whether the current user has a role of manager for my project module
    query = """select COUNT(*) from res_groups_users_rel where uid=%d and gid=%d """ % (user_id.id, user_tiq_id)
    self.env.cr.execute(query)
    result = self.env.cr.fetchall()

    # convert the  string count into a integer
    json_result = json.dumps(result, ensure_ascii=False)
    count = json_result.strip('\' \" [] ')
    str_count = str(count)
    int_count = int(str_count)
    if int_count != 0:
        self.identify_manager = True
    else:
        self.identify_manager = False
```

Then I edit the chatter.js file in mail module. Here I replce

```
on_open_composer_new_message: function () {
           this.open_composer();},
```

code by

```
on_open_composer_new_message: function () {
    var Model = require('web.DataModel');
    var manager = this;     
    new Model('project.task').query(['identify_manager'])
                        .filter([['active', '=', true]])
                        .first()
                        .then(function(uid) {
                            console.log(uid);
                            if (uid.identify_manager == true){
                               manager.open_composer();
                            }else{ 
                                alert("You can not proceed this action.");
                            }
                            });

},
```

This method is work fine for me... when user click on the 'New Message' button it gives the alert and when Manage clicks it open the message composer.